# Pretty url runs even with duplicate url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have dynamic website and I made product name (cafeteria-table) to show when the page runs like below:

```
https://example.com/subcategory/cafeteria-table
```

Now if I edit characters in this product name (cafeteria-table) like i mentioned below it should show 404 error since it's duplicate pretty url :

```
https://example.com/subcategory/cafeteria
```

the page shouldn't run but still i can see page with header and footer with blank page and this is affecting seo.

This is my Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
Redirect 301 /subcategory/cafe%20chairs https://example.com/subcategory/cafe-chairs

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [R,L]

#RewriteRule ^category/chairs$   category/index.php
RewriteRule ^category/.*$   category/index.php  
RewriteRule ^subcategory/.*$   subcategory/index.php 
RewriteRule ^products/.*$   products/index.php 
RewriteRule ^products/.*/.*$   products/index.php 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your rule `RewriteRule ^subcategory/.*$   subcategory/index.php` matches any characters in URI after `/subcategory/` . Change its pattern to `^subcategory/.+\-.+$` so that can can only rewrite the desired URL path

Comment: Sir, There's no change if i remove any characters there's still empty page running but i want 404 error

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts if you could mention like FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite in your question then it will make it more easier, thank you.

Comment: as you can see the first url i mentioned above cafeteria-table is original product name and it runs successfully but if i edit any characters in it and run like cafeteria-t still my page runs with blank page

Comment: @AmruthaCGowda, No, please do mention like. if I type `http://localhost:80/singh-test-123/test/` I want it to redirect on browser to `http://localhost:80/singh` which should be served by `index.php` file in backend, like this manner for all URLs then only we can get clear picture of your question, else it will be a Guess game, cheers.

Comment: sure now i've edited the question sir hope you understand.

Comment: @AmruthaCGowda, Sorry to say its still not clear. So you want to change url in browser from `https://example.com/subcategory/cafeteria-table` TO `https://example.com/subcategory/cafeteria` but which file is responsible to serve this page? eg: index.php or any other php or any html file? Like that mention for all URLs in your question to make it clear.

Comment: No i don't want anything to change or redirect but if i remove or edit product name characters in url it should show 404 error

Comment: Is this a WordPress website?

Comment: no it is html website